# get CGRect location in superview objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to print out the x coordinate of a CGRect. The x,y coordinates of the rect is set to where the user touches, like this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches]anyObject];
    startPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    jrect = CGRectMake(startPoint.x, startPoint.y, 100, 100);
    CGContextAddRect(ctx, jrect);
    CGContextFillPath(ctx);
}
```

I could just print out the startPoint but if I would print out the CGRect's coordinate I tried to do this:

```
int jrectX = lroundf(CGRectGetMinX(jrect));

xlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"x: %i", jrectX];
```

But the number it returns doesn't make any sense at all, sometimes they are bigger to the left than to the right. Is there anything wrong with the code?

Answer (score 2):

A CGRect is a struct with four CGFloat properties: x, y, width, height

To print the x value from a CGRect:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", rect.x]
```

To print the entire rect, there's a convenience function:

```
NSStringFromCGRect(rect)
```

You're having problems above, because you're storing the x value into an int, and then using a float rounding function on it. So it should be:

```
CGFloat jrectX = CGRectGetMinX(jrect);
```

. . . unless you're doing rotation transformation, you can just use:

```
CGFloat jrectX = jrect.origin.x;
```

Comment: updated the answer with a point about CGRectGetMinX vs rect.origin.x

Answer (score 0):

DR.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DR : UIView
{
    CGContextRef ctx;
    CGRect jrect;
    CGPoint startPoint;

    UILabel *xlabel;
}

@end
```

DR.m file.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
         xlabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
        [self addSubview:xlabel];
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    jrect = CGRectMake(startPoint.x, startPoint.y, 100, 100);

    CGContextAddRect(ctx, jrect);
    CGContextFillPath(ctx);
    // Drawing code
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches]anyObject];
    startPoint = [touch locationInView:self];

    int jrectX = lroundf(CGRectGetMinX(jrect));

    NSLog(@"jrectX --------------");
    xlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"x: %i", jrectX];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

@end
```

In other viewController use it...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    DR *drr=[[DR alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
    [drr setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

    [self.view addSubview:drr];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

[image]